# how to see if any element of a list contains only a certain value in R

Tags: r, list, loops, if-statement, matrix

I have a list of many matrices, let say my_list. I want to check if any of those matrices has only zero s as its element and if so which matrix in that list has such situation.

```
library(R.utils)
output_vec <- vector()
for(i in 1:length(my_list)){
   asZero(as.vector(my_list[[i]]))}
```

this gives me true falses but, I am not able to return the index of matrices with all zero elements. I appreciate any help with this.

Comment: You are missing a `)` and the function is called `isZero`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We may need to wrap with `all` - loop over the `list` of matrices with `sapply`, create a logical expression (`x == 0`), wrap with `all` to return a single TRUE/FALSE - if all values excluding NAs (`na.rm = TRUE`) are 0, this returns TRUE or else FALSe

```
sapply(my_list, function(x) all(x == 0, na.rm = TRUE))
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use `norm` to judge if all entries in the matrix is zeros, e.g.,

```
sapply(my_list, norm) == 0
```

since the norm of matrix is `0` if and only if all values are zeros.

---

## Example

```
> my_list
[[1]]
     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]    0    0    0
[2,]    0    0    0
[3,]    0    0    0

[[2]]
     [,1] [,2]
[1,]    1    1
[2,]    0    0


> sapply(my_list, norm) == 0
[1]  TRUE FALSE
```

Comment: Nice use of `svd`

Comment: I see. this is a very interesting idea!